# How to code remove NA in "with" base in R

Tags: r, na, with-statement, coefficients, non-linear-regression

My simple data set look like the following.

```
+--------+------+--------+-----+-----+
|  Time  | Firm |  Out   | Lab | Cap |
+--------+------+--------+-----+-----+
| Jan-00 | A    | 161521 | 261 | 13  |
| Feb-00 | A    | 142452 | 334 | 15  |
| Mar-00 | A    | 365697 | 156 | 14  |
| Apr-00 | A    | 355789 | 134 | 12  |
| May-00 | A    | 376843 | 159 | 15  |
| Jun-00 | A    | 258762 | 119 | 12  |
| Jul-00 | A    | 255447 | 41  | 45  |
| Aug-00 | A    | 188545 | 247 | 75  |
| Sep-00 | A    | 213663 | 251 | NA  |
| Oct-00 | A    | 273209 | 62  | 12  |
| Nov-00 | A    | 317468 | 525 | 15  |
| Dec-00 | A    | 238668 | 217 | 16  |
| Jan-01 | B    | 241286 | 298 | 42  |
| Feb-01 | B    | 135288 | 109 | 45  |
| Mar-01 | B    | 363609 | 7   | 24  |
| Apr-01 | B    | 318472 | NA  | 56  |
| May-01 | B    | 446279 | 0   | 12  |
| Jun-01 | B    | 390230 | 50  | 12  |
| Jul-01 | B    | 118945 | 143 | 45  |
| Aug-01 | B    | 174887 | 85  | NA  |
| Sep-01 | B    | 183770 | 80  | 15  |
| Oct-01 | B    | 197832 | 214 | 12  |
| Nov-01 | B    | 317468 | 525 | 15  |
| Dec-01 | B    | 238668 | 217 | 16  |
+--------+------+--------+-----+-----+
```

The above data set can be reproduced using the following code.

```
    structure(list(Time = structure(c(9L, 7L, 15L, 1L, 17L, 13L, 
    11L, 3L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 2L, 18L, 14L, 12L, 
    4L, 24L, 22L, 20L, 6L), .Label = c("Apr-00", "Apr-01", "Aug-00", 
    "Aug-01", "Dec-00", "Dec-01", "Feb-00", "Feb-01", "Jan-00", "Jan-01", 
    "Jul-00", "Jul-01", "Jun-00", "Jun-01", "Mar-00", "Mar-01", "May-00", 
    "May-01", "Nov-00", "Nov-01", "Oct-00", "Oct-01", "Sep-00", "Sep-01"
    ), class = "factor"), Firm = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Out = c(161521L, 
    142452L, 365697L, 355789L, 376843L, 258762L, 255447L, 188545L, 
    213663L, 273209L, 317468L, 238668L, 241286L, 135288L, 363609L, 
    318472L, 446279L, 390230L, 118945L, 174887L, 183770L, 197832L, 
    317468L, 238668L), Lab = c(261L, 334L, 156L, 134L, 159L, 119L, 
    41L, 247L, 251L, 62L, 525L, 217L, 298L, 109L, 7L, NA, 0L, 50L, 
    143L, 85L, 80L, 214L, 525L, 217L), Cap = c(13L, 15L, 14L, 12L, 
    15L, 12L, 45L, 75L, NA, 12L, 15L, 16L, 42L, 45L, 24L, 56L, 12L, 
    12L, 45L, NA, 15L, 12L, 15L, 16L)), .Names = c("Time", "Firm", 
    "Out", "Lab", "Cap"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -24L))
```

First I get the panel structure for the panel data regression using the following command

```
    library(zoo)
    library(plm)

    Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
    dat["time1"] <- as.yearmon(dat$Time,format="%b-%y")
    pdat <-pdata.frame(dat,index=c("Firm","time1"))
```

Now run the regression

```
    Model1<- plm(Out ~ Lab+Cap+I(0.5*(Lab^2))
                +I(0.5*(Cap^2))+I(Lab*Cap),data=pdat)
    summary(Model1)
```

Then short cuts are created for the resulted estimates as below.

```
    a1 <- coef( Model1 )[ "Lab" ]
    a2 <- coef( Model1 )["Cap"]
    a11 <- coef( Model1  )[ "I(0.5*(Lab^2))" ]
    b22 <- coef( Model1  )[ "I(0.5*(Cap^2))" ]
    a12 <-a21<- coef( Model1  )[ "I(Lab*Cap)" ]

    pdat$mpLab <- with( pdat,+ a1 + a11 * a1 + a12*a2)
```

I have this code to calculate marginal product of area. But my data frame has got some missing values and I need to include the code to remove those missing values from the above calculation. Otherwise the answer also comes as NA. I just tried to include below at the end of above code.

```
    pdat$mpLab <- with( pdat,+ a1 + a11 * a1 + a12*a2,na.rm=TRUE)
```

But it does not take that tag.The dataframe pdat is a panel data set analysed using panel data regression. a1, a2,a11,a12 are coefficients of the particular regression. pdat has some missing data and I believe this pdat$mpLab gives NA for the each observation due to that missing data in the pdat.

Much appreciated if anybody can help me.

Comment: It would be great if you could supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. That way others can also befit form your question, and the accompanying answer, in the future.  You can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: How do you want to treat these NAs? Replace them by zeroes?

Comment: You could try `rowSums(with(pdat, cbind(a1, a11*a1, a12*a2)), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @Eric Fail I edited my question

Comment: @Marat Talipov _ no I want to keep the missing values as it is and not to replace by zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure this is the problem you are referring to, but this is definitely a problem in the code you submitted : some indices of model coefficients where not correctly typed, they are missing a few space characters. When the indices don't exist, NAs are returned.

When I used the correct typing:

```
a1 <- coef( Model1 )[ "Lab" ]
a2 <- coef( Model1 )["Cap"]
a11 <- coef( Model1  )[ "I(0.5 * (Lab^2))" ]
b22 <- coef( Model1  )[ "I(0.5 * (Cap^2))" ]
a12 <-a21<- coef( Model1  )[ "I(Lab * Cap)" ]
```

I did get all coefficients having values, and

```
pdat$mpLab <- with( pdat,+ a1 + a11 * a1 + a12*a2)
```

did populate the dataframe.

Hope this is what you want

Comment: Yes it's working with your coding correction for my simple data set, but still not with my big data set

Comment: @Doo then you'll have to make a test dataset that reproduces

Comment: I figured out. That was a problem with space in the code as you indicated.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `+` to compute rowwise sums and for that there's a special function `rowSums` which also has a `na.rm =` argument. I use `cbind` create a matrix of the columns you want to sum and then apply `rowSums(..., na.rm = TRUE)`, so it could look like this:

```
pdat$earea <- rowSums(with(pdat, cbind(a1, a11*a1, a12*a2)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Here's an example with some fake data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(a1 = c(1:4, NA), a11 = sample(5), a12 = c(NA, 2:5), a2 = sample(5))
x$check <- rowSums(with(x, cbind(a1, a11*a1, a12*a2)), na.rm = TRUE) 
x
#  a1 a11 a12 a2 check
#1  1   2  NA  5     3
#2  2   5   2  4    20
#3  3   4   3  2    21
#4  4   3   4  3    28
#5 NA   1   5  1     5
```

Comment: @   docendo discimus I edited my question with the codes and the data set.